How to map a variable to a string in nginx
I can make this map directive work:
map directive - allow origin
map $http_origin $allow_origin {
   ~^https?://localhost$      $http_origin;
   ~^https?://(www)?mysite\.co\.uk$ $http_origin;
   default "";
}

Equivalent if statement - allow origin:
if ($http_origin ~ '^https?://(localhost|mysite\.co\.uk)$') {
  $allow_origin=$http_origin;
}


Now I want to create another map directive based on the first one to determine if cred is true:
map directive - cred
map $http_origin $cred {
   '$allow_origin' true;
   default false;
}

Equivalent if statement - cred:
if ($http_origin ~ '^https?://(localhost|mysite\.co\.uk)$') {
  $cred=true;
}

But it always returns false
How can I fix this?
thanks

I decided instead to match the second variable against empty regex
map $http_origin $cors_origin {
   ~^https?://localhost$      $http_origin;
   ~^https?://(www)?mysite\.co\.uk$ $http_origin;
   default "";
}
map "$cors_origin" $cors_cred {
   ~^$ false;
   default true;
}

